# Journey Builder: How to add more Entry Data objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm creating a journey in Journey Builder using Saleforce Data as the entry. When I get to the 4th stage of setting this up using Entry Data, I need to add a further object/fields to this list.

How do I add further objects into here?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add objects that have a relationship to either the object from which you inject someone into the journey, or a relationship to the injected contact.

An example:

You inject a Contact based on a case changing status to closed. You can in your Entry Data select any object that has a relationship to either Case or Contact:
[image]
No other objects will be available for you to choose in step 4.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Marketing Cloud Connect configured, you can add any available Salesforce objects and fields using [Synchronized Data Sources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_integration_for_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5) in [Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_builder.htm&type=5).

After you set up a new object, you can sync any of the available fields for that specific object. These objects and fields will then be available in Journey Builder as well as in the synchronized data extensions folder to query and build segments.

Hope this helps!